# ASM - can't instrument java/lang/Thread

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I am able to instrument a boat load of my own classes and some third party libraries. But, when I want to load java/lang/Thread (need the thread id and name to link parent thread and child threads), the class is not even loading.

The code that checks whether a class needs to be instrumented or not happens inside class visitor's transform().

```
    public ClassVisitor transform(ClassVisitor cv, String className, ClassDesc classDesc) {
        System.out.println("className : " + className);
        Configuration config = Configuration.getInstance();
        if (!className.contains("$") && (!config.isToBeExcluded(className) || ThreadHelper.isThreadClass(className))) {
            System.out.println("Included className : " + className);
            return new HttpServiceCVT(cv, className);
        }
        return cv;
```

The print statement before that check, prints all the loaded classes. I see a lot of classes from java/lang/ package but not java/lang/Thread.

Has anyone instrumented thread class? What am I missing?

Please don't get mad at Sysout's. It was a just for a quick debug. I didn't expect to get stuck here.

*************Update based on @JohannesKuhn comment.**

Tried to retransform classes by adding below line in my agent
`inst.retransformClasses(Class.forName("java.lang.Thread"));`
Ran into JVM crashes, so modified the code to just instrument the Thread class and init (not ) method.
Instrumenting "init" works but errors out for a different method that is not instrumented. Output below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError 
 - klass: 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError'
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (exceptions.cpp:427), pid=12444, tid=0x0000000000000c03
#  fatal error: ExceptionMark destructor expects no pending exceptions
```

corresponding code

```
    if(this.className.equals("java/lang/Thread") && name.equals("init")) {
        return new TracerMV(access, name, desc, mv, true, className);
    }else {
        System.out.println( "not init so returning mv for method  " + name);
        return mv;
    }
```

Does this mean the code is trying to instrument java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError? If so, how is it doing it as I have set the filters to just transform the thread class.

Comment: `java.lang.Thread` is one of those classes that are initialized very early in the VM lifetime - before your agent even runs. You may request that `java.lang.Thread` is [retransformed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses%26java.lang.Class...%27).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, I followed your advise and was able to transform java.lang.Thread. Unfortunately, running into a different problem. Updated the question with more details.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what kind of changes you made to the code.